# Supervised Invocation of Runnables on Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, runnable, executorservice

Alright, i'll explain what i am asking by giving an exemple.

lets say im trying to implement a parallel merging algorithm when given:

*db* is an array where *db[i]* is an ArrayList of objects.

*j* is its size.
*Merger(db,cmp,i,j)* is a runnable that merges *db[ j ]* **into** *db[i].*

cmp is a relevant Comparator.

This is what i have Firstly Done:

```
    ExecutorService e =  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    while (j>0) 
        for ( i=0;i<j;i++,j--) 
            e.execute(new Merger<E>(db,cmp,i,j));
```

but then some merges were started while previous merges that needed to be finished first were not yet finished. (not to mention that the running thread finished the loop way before the merging was finished...) and that made my program kick out an Exeception.

This is what I CANT DO, but WANT TO DO, and therefore need your help:

```
    ExecutorService e =  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    while (j>0) {
        for ( i=0;i<j;i++,j--) 
            e.execute(new Merger<E>(db,cmp,i,j));
        wait for e to announce that all runnables have finished running;
    }
```

in my opinion this should work, if you think not then explain why, but anyway, i want to know how its done.

(basicly i can implement my own version of FixedThreadPool to make it heppen but i rather not)

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for a [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html):

- Determine the number of threads you need to wait for and create a `CountDownLatch` with that number
- Pass the latch to all worker threads when constructing them and have them call `countDown()` once they finish.
- After the loop that enqueues worker threads, `await()` that the countdown reaches zero.

Answer (score 1):

You need a 'startAndRendezvous' runnable that issues merges and waits for them to complete.  Usually, this is done by creating a set of merge runnable tasks set with a callback pointing to a CountDownlatch in the startAndRendezvous or, more flexibly, pass the startAndRendezvous as a constructor parameter to the merge runnables.

Latest Java has a ForkJoinPool.  Look at the class - it saves having an explicit countdown latch.

Comment: like how? your answer is too abstract

Answer (score -1):

An easy way that should work is to define a static counter in Merger:

```
public class Merger<E> ... {
  public static int runningCount=0;
  public Merger(...){
    runningCount++;
  }
  public void run(){
     ...
     runnningCount--;
  }
}
```

Then :

```
ExecutorService e =  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);    
while (j>0) {
    for ( i=0;i<j;i++,j--) 
        e.execute(new Merger<E>(db,cmp,i,j));
    while(Merger.runningCount>0)
        Thread.sleep(10);
}
```

Comment: runningCount needs to be an AtomicInteger or that won't work. And spin-locking is rarely the best idea -- even if the loop has a Thread.sleep.

Comment: @yshavit = yes, or locked up.  The sleep() loop is just bad  - there is Wait/Notify, for example.  Also, now there is ForkJoinPool class.

Comment: thank you for the feedback, I did not that. Solution by @Philipp Reichart looks better